# Dragging and slinging a body in box2d

Tags: box2d, andengine

I am trying to use Physics to allow a user to drag a sprite and have it move in the direction the user dragged it in when the user lifts his or her finger up.

For example, if the user drags it hard or with force, the body moves faster in that direction. If they drag it slow, the body moves slower in that direction.

My game is in Portrait mode not landscape.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As user drags get the touch position and  update body position.If user moves fast or slow, body will update position  based on motion. 
If user moves slow, then body also update position based on movement